# Apache http Server Configuration (Jasper Server Load Balancer Configuration)

Tags: tomcat, jasperserver

Please help me with below issue.

We have Installed the Apache Http Server 2.2.25 in my Windows 7 system.
We have Installed the 2 tomcat in 2 physical systems and bonded the tomcat with Jasper server
we have configured the Httpd.conf file and also created the workers.properties file.
The workers.properties file contains as below,

```
worker.list=worker1,worker2  
worker.list=balancer  

worker.worker1.port=8080  
worker.worker1.host=***.***.*.****  
worker.worker1.type=ajp13  
worker.worker1.lbfactor=2  

worker.worker2.port=1111  
worker.worker2.host=***.***.*.**** 
worker.worker2.type=ajp13  
worker.worker2.lbfactor=3  

worker.balancer.type=lb  
worker.balancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2  
worker.balancer.method=B  
worker.balancer.sticky_session=True
```

We are getting the below error,

```
[info]  jk_ajp_common.c (945): (worker1) Tomcat has forced a connection close for socket 732.  
[error] jk_ajp_common.c (1592): (worker1) Tomcat is down or refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet).  
[info]  jk_ajp_common.c (1902): (worker1) receiving from tomcat failed, recoverable operation attempt=0.  
[info]  jk_ajp_common.c (1941): (worker1) sending request to tomcat failed,  recoverable operation attempt=1.  
[info]  jk_ajp_common.c (945): (worker1) Tomcat has forced a connection close for socket 732.  
[error] jk_ajp_common.c (1592): (worker1) Tomcat is down or refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet).  
[info]  jk_ajp_common.c (1902): (worker1) receiving from tomcat failed, recoverable operation attempt=1.  
[info]  jk_ajp_common.c (1941): (worker1) sending request to tomcat failed,  recoverable operation attempt=2.  
[error] jk_ajp_common.c (1953): (worker1) Connecting to tomcat failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port.  
[info]  jk_lb_worker.c (1098): service failed, worker worker1 is in error state.
```

Thanks a lot in advance.
B Rama Krishna

Answer (score 0):

You must use port 8009 or the port you have configured in your tomcat to AJP connector.

See also:

- [The Apache Tomcat Connector - Generic HowTo](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/workers.html)
- [The AJP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. after doing the changes with respect to the above link we are getting the same error. Can you please suggest me some more links